# Problemas para mandar valores a una función y para retonar C/C++

Tags: c++, c

En el programa tengo esto, donde quiero que el valor de mi función sea guardado en la variable " **nombre** " de mi struct, pero aparece el siguiente error:

**[Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char [100]'**

```
while(sal==false){
                clean
                memset(alumno[num].nombre,0,sizeof(alumno[num].nombre));
                alumno[num].nombre=nombres(num);
                getch();
                sal=volver();
                num++;
            }
```

.

Ahora, en mi función(la tengo en una librería) tengo otro problema, el cual aparece a la hora de retornar el valor, el error es:

**[Error] invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]**

```
char nombres(int a){
int i;
char str[100];
bool e=false;
while(e==false){
    clean
    cout<<verde<<"\n\n\n        Alta de Registro "<<cyan<<a<<"\n    "<<reset<<"Dime el nombre del alumno"<<endl;
    memset(str,0,sizeof(str));
    gets(str);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){ 
        if((isalpha(str[i]))||(str[i]==' '))
            e=true;
        else{
            e=false;
            cout<<rojoc<<"[error]"<<reset"solo admitire letras";
            i=101;
        }
    }   
}
return (str);
```

}

.

Le he dado vueltas pero desconozco completamente de como arreglarlo Dx.
Gracias por leerme uwu.

pd: **num** lo uso como indice para saber en que registro voy.

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Las preguntas que incluyen imágenes en lugar de texto suelen tener una acogida pésima en el sitio. Principalmente porque no se puede copiapegar el texto, ni realizar búsquedas en ellas. Por mi parte añado que no puedo compilar imágenes y como además soy daltónico, no veo el texto ¿No es mucho más fácil poner el código en lugar de una imagen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'

El error es claro, conversión invalida de `char*` a `char`; en el prototipo de la función declaras que su valor de retorno es un `char`, pero le tratas de retornar un puntero a char(`char*`).

Estas declarando un vector `char` de 100 posiciones llamado str, al tratar de retornar str realmente lo que estas haciendo es retornando el puntero a la primera posición del vector, osea un `char*`, por eso se te queja el compilador.

Ahora, ¿por qué lo haces de esa manera?, estas en C++, por ende utiliza los objetos de C++, como `string` por ejemplo, a menos que tengas una razón de peso para hacerlo así.